# Understanding HAProxy statistics web

Tags: haproxy, statistics, stats

I would like to understand the parameters shown in the HAProxy stats web interface.
What's `maxsock` parameter about? And `current conns` in general process information´? Why it isn't the same as current sessions in backend?

I have Google Analytics too, monitoring our website, but the users in Analytics and sessions are not the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `maxsock` value is the maximum number of sockets that the HAProxy process can create. On most installations I've seen, it's exactly equal to the value for `ulimit-n`, meaning it's automatically computed.

> ulimit-n [number]
>   Sets the maximum number of per-process file-descriptors to [number]. By
>   default, it is automatically computed, so it is recommended not to use this
>   option.

As for `current conn`, that's the sum total of all inbound connections to the process. If you add up the `scur` (in CSV) or `Session - Cur` (in the web interface) for all `Listen` or `Frontend` blocks, you'll find that the numbers are identical.

Google Analytics doesn't have the same view of your website, so the numbers should be close-ish but not identical.